# How to install LTE USB Huawei EE3372 on Raspberry pi zero?

Tags: networking, usb, pi-zero, internet, modem

HELP !

I never worked on Rasperry before, only arduino. Been trying for some time now to install LTE USB modem, Huawei EE3372 on a Raspberry pi zero. Found several instructions on the internet, some here and some on other places, some even saying it should work automatically, but none of the instructions worked. Almost always half of the commands didn't work.

I am on the end of my wits if some one can help me this, give me clear simple instructions I would be more then grateful.

Thanks to anyone who donates his time

Comment: Do you have a USB to micro USB adapter to connect the stick to the Pi Zero? If yes and it is plugged in what is the output of the command `ip address`? On a Pi 3 you would see an (additional) eth device (eth1). The stick appears to the operating system like an additional Ethernet device. Be aware that the stick requires quite a lot of power so make sure you are supplying enough.

Comment: Consider [this](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476): unless you tell which commands failed (and how), there's no way for people to guess what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just quit with this approach in the end and choose to use smartphone instead for the task I had at hand.
Much simpler with an app.
Thanks PiEntusiast for help though.